# Couchbase: Error while writing object to bucket

Tags: couchbase

I have a web app, where couchbase bucket is deleted and then recreated while clearing the cache (as flush didn't help the scenario). I am using REST API with auth type sasl and proxy port 11211 for creating. The _mcache variable is re-initialized with the information in the config file after bucket recreation.

I got an error while trying to cache the object after recreation....Thought of timing issue, added sleep after recreation that didn't help either. Here's the log file snippet.

I know I am lagging something here, seeking advice.

```
2012-11-30 11:27:19 [DEBUG] 5 Enyim.Caching.Memcached.MemcachedNode.InternalPoolImpl - Releasing socket 99103fd0-e03d-4fb8-b2b3-089ce27fc241
2012-11-30 11:27:19 [DEBUG] 5 Enyim.Caching.Memcached.MemcachedNode.InternalPoolImpl - Are we alive? True
2012-11-30 11:27:19 [DEBUG] 5 Enyim.Caching.Memcached.MemcachedNode.InternalPoolImpl - Acquiring stream from pool. 192.168.70.156:11210
2012-11-30 11:27:19 [DEBUG] 5 Enyim.Caching.Memcached.PooledSocket - Socket 99103fd0-e03d-4fb8-b2b3-089ce27fc241 was reset
2012-11-30 11:27:19 [DEBUG] 5 Enyim.Caching.Memcached.MemcachedNode.InternalPoolImpl - Socket was reset. 99103fd0-e03d-4fb8-b2b3-089ce27fc241
2012-11-30 11:27:19 [DEBUG] 5 Couchbase.VBucketAwareOperationFactory.VBGet - Key egfWeo2Xrr1enrI/0gxiqvsNXOe2vHkfNCoh4Lq6UFv0uqAwg+MAvcTYrGMeCBf0KTPL/wEFA7iQqbCWWYbWTw== was mapped to 124
2012-11-30 11:27:19 [DEBUG] 5 Enyim.Caching.Memcached.MemcachedNode.InternalPoolImpl - Releasing socket 99103fd0-e03d-4fb8-b2b3-089ce27fc241
2012-11-30 11:27:19 [DEBUG] 5 Enyim.Caching.Memcached.MemcachedNode.InternalPoolImpl - Are we alive? True
2012-11-30 11:27:20 [ERROR] 6 Couchbase.MessageStreamListener - The infinite loop just finished, probably the server closed the connection without errors. (?)
2012-11-30 11:27:20 [DEBUG] 6 Couchbase.MessageStreamListener - ReadMessage failed with exception: - System.IO.IOException: Remote host closed the streaming connection
   at Couchbase.MessageStreamListener.ReadMessages(Uri heartBeatUrl, Uri configUrl)
   at Couchbase.MessageStreamListener.ProcessPool()
2012-11-30 11:27:20 [DEBUG] 6 Couchbase.MessageStreamListener - Reached the retry limit, rethrowing. - System.IO.IOException: Remote host closed the streaming connection
   at Couchbase.MessageStreamListener.ReadMessages(Uri heartBeatUrl, Uri configUrl)
   at Couchbase.MessageStreamListener.ProcessPool()
```

Comment: Can you give us more information ?

- Which version of Couchbase are you using?

- how do you create/flush your bucket?
Are you using http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-admin-restapi-flushing-bucket.html ?

- How your Web application access your data? 
Could you confirm that you are using a client SDK to access the database. (usually developers do not have to use the memcached protocol directly)

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it is hard to provide a complete answer, but here some ideas.

As you said it could be because the bucket/node has not come back online yet after deleting/recreating the bucket. Have you tried, at least for testing to wait "longer" ? (I know that is not a viable workaround, but it is to help identifying the source of the issue.)

I think it is important to understand why the *flush* does not work since it is the proper approach for what you need.

Once again, it will be great if you can provide more information, and also check that you are using the latest client library.